# VNC server run at boot - authentication problem

Tags: boot, server, vnc, password

I followed [This tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/) to install and run a VNC server on my Pi using tightvnc.
Everything works great when I start the server through SSH but I wanted it to start at boot.
So I wrote the script to make that happen and updated the boot sequence to make sure the script actually runs.
Here is the script:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: vncboot
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start VNC Server at boot time
# Description: Start VNC Server at boot time.
### END INIT INFO

#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/vncboot

USER=pi
HOME=/home/pi

export USER HOME

case "$1" in
 start)
  echo "Starting VNC Server"
  #Insert your favoured settings for a VNC session
  su - pi -c "/usr/bin/vncserver :0 -geometry 1280x800 -depth 16 -pixelformat rgb565"
  ;;

 stop)
  echo "Stopping VNC Server"
  /usr/bin/vncserver -kill :0
  ;;

 *)
  echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/vncboot {start|stop}"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac

exit 0
```

The script runs and when trying to connect with Remmina on my laptop it actually recognize the vnc server and tries to authenticate.
The problem is, the script does not specify a password or anything, so Remmina can't connect and keeps asking me for a password that I can't provide.
Is there a solution to set the VNC server password at its creation when the RPi boots?

Comment: Might be a good idea to post this to the RPF forums at raspberrypi.org as it's their tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the `vncpasswd` utilty.

Normally you should be prompted to enter the password the first time you run vncserver.

Try `man vncpasswd` for more detail.

Comment: What you suggest works great when I start the server through SSH. However, this is intended to auto-start at boot, when there is no keyboard or display connected to the RPi. I'm not sure I understand how this would work here, I'll look into vncpasswd tonight.

Comment: Aight, I just lauched the utility under SSH and defined the password. works great now.