# How does one setup and run tightvncserver on Raspberry PI?

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-jessie, remote, vnc

I am very new to tightvncserver on Raspberry PI. So, I researched online and I am still confused. First, I came across this webpage [How to setup tightvncserver](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/) on Raspberry PI website about tightvncserver and I did not find any option in the Raspi-Config to enable tightvncserver. So, I ended up manually installing tightvncserver and don't know how to start or set it up. I tried to connect to PI's tightvncserver using tigervncviewer and it refused to connect. Could someone please give me some guidance. I am running Raspbian
Jessie.

Comment: You have to run `tightvncserver`. It asks for a password. It is possible then to have it start on boot - this requires a script.

Comment: You do not state the OS you are using. If it is Raspbian then it will be installed with the desktop version (not lite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote up a how-to for TigerVNC, which you can easily modify for tightvnc. See https://github.com/gitbls/RPiVNCHowTo/blob/master/README.md. Oh, I just noticed that you’re using Jessie, not Stretch. I haven’t tested it on Jessie, since it’s old and moldy and no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

The following provides a way to set password, although you are normally prompted to do this on first run [Set VNC password](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/34984/8697)
To set up to run on boot [Start VNC on Jessie at boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39374/8697)

Answer (score 1):

First, upgrade to Raspberry Pi Os Buster.

`raspi-config` configures RealVNC VNC server. If you enable it, `raspi-config` issues these commands under the covers:

```
apt-get install realvnc-vnc-server
systemctl enable vncserver-x11-serviced.service
systemctl start vncserver-x11-serviced.service
```